# Rainfall pattern Recognition / Classification using Neural Network

Tags: matlab, matrix, neural-network, classification, pattern-recognition

I am working on assignment titled "Pattern Recognition of Rainfall using ANN". for training and validation proposes, i have time-series rainfall data ranging from 1976 - 2006 of two metro-logical stations.. I have arranged the data in EXCEL from where i import and convert it into matrices . Input matrix contains 480 * 5 . where 480 cloums with 5 rows representing

> Year, Month, Longitude, Latitude and elevation
>
> , Output matrix contains mean rainfall(mm) value of that month with
> size of 480 * 1.

for example
Input parameters are

> 1976    1    31.5400    74.2200    214

and output is

> 23.9000

I have used PattternNet "" and code is below

```
 net = patternnet(10);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

load Input
load Target
P = transpose(Input); 
T = transpose(Target); 
x=P;
y=T;


[net,tr] = train(net,x,y);
nntraintool
view(net)
% The network outputs will be in the range 0 to 1,
% so we can use vec2ind function to get the class indices as the position of the highest element in each output vector.
testX = x(:,tr.testInd);
testT = y(:,tr.testInd);
testY = net(testX);
testIndices = vec2ind(testY)
% the overall percentages of correct and incorrect classification.
[c,cm] = confusion(testT,testY)
fprintf('Percentage Correct Classification   : %f%%\n', 100*(1-c));
fprintf('Percentage Incorrect Classification : %f%%\n', 100*c);
% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, plotconfusion(targets,outputs)
%figure, ploterrhist(errors)
```

I transpose the Inputs and output values but results are not satisfactory because

> Percentage Correct Classification = 85%
>
> Best validation performance graph values are lying on same axis for all epochs
>
> regression value is 27.36
>
> ROC line is on 0 in training, validations and testing

Are the above parameters of Inputs and Targets are in correct form and valid for accurate and precise results ? am i using correct way / code for this propose? any suggestions please.

Thanks for your time....!

Comment: Why are the results not satisfactory? I cannot reproduce the results if you do not add data, but I suspect that is too large.

Comment: because result of correct classification is 85 % and best validation performance is lying on same x,y of plot for all epochs

Comment: what is the purpose of transposing? can you test it after removing transpose on Inputs and Outputs?

Comment: yes i remove transpose function and caught into error "Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples".

Comment: @A.Visser.. can i say this data time series? however, i also make objects of time-series but this network was not accepting the time-series object